# Two foreign keys referring to one primary key

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key, primary-key

I'd to create a database that records transactions between two users. A user can transfer points (think of it as money) to another user. `user` table looks like:

```
| userID        |    name       |      email       |   balance  |
| ------------- |---------------|------------------|------------|
| 101           | alpha         | alpha@mail.com   |   1000     |
| 102           | bravo         | bravo@mail.com   |    500     |
| 103           | charlie       | charlie@mail.com |   2000     |
```

And the `transaction` table should look like:

```
| transactionID |  from_user    |   to_user        | transfer_amount  |
| ------------- |---------------|------------------|------------------|
|   1           | 101           |       103        |   100            |
|   2           | 102           |       101        |   150            |
|   3           | 102           |       103        |   200            |
```

I tried to draw a schema with [Vertableo](https://vertabelo.com/) which doesn't seem have *one to zero or many* relationship option. But a user might not send or receive points at all, so the relationship should be *one to zero or many*. However, this schema on Vertableo throws the error **reference name must be unique**.

[image]

Could someone give hints to draw a schema or provide SQL code?

Comment: If you tag the question with the RDBMS this is for, then someone might be able to suggest suitable SQL `CREATE` statements.

Comment: Added your recommended tags. Hoping it helps.

Comment: @moazzem: dbdemon wasn't talking about the `rdbms` tag, but a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Oh okay. I'll be using MySQL. Added `mysql` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example SQL code (create with MySQL Workbench):

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`user` (
  `iduser` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`));


CREATE TABLE `test`.`transfer` (
  `transactionID` INT NOT NULL,
  `from_user` INT NULL,
  `to_user` INT NULL,
  `transfer_amount` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `from_user_key_idx` (`from_user` ASC),
  INDEX `to_user_key_idx` (`to_user` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `from_user_key`
    FOREIGN KEY (`from_user`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`user` (`iduser`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `to_user_key`
    FOREIGN KEY (`to_user`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`user` (`iduser`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

This works. However if you want to query the 'transfer'-table and want to substitute the IDs for usernames it gets a bit more complicated. Heres an example query:

```
select a.username as from_user, b.username as to_user, transfer_amount
from transfer
inner join user a
on transfer.from_user = a.iduser
inner join user b
on transfer.to_user = b.iduser;
```